# EsLint or Create React App - Cordova is not defined

Tags: cordova, webpack, eslint, create-react-app

I'm writing a React App that also runs in Cordova and uses Create React App.

It won't compile when I add `cordova.exec`to one of the cordova functions

I've tried adding it to the EsLint config

esLintrc.js

```
"env": {
        "browser": true,
        "mocha": true,
        "es6": true,
        "cordova": true,
    },

"globals": {
"document": true,
"cordova": true,
"window": true
},
```

Any idea where else I can add it?

Answer (score 0):

Duh..

`window['cordova'].exec` works